# Can't Seem To Find Where SQL Statement Went Wrong

Tags: php, mysql

I'm probably just way too tired and am missing something really simple but I can't figure it out.

Attempting to execute the following query:

```
INSERT INTO chars (charName,charClass,charLevel,charLife,charES,charInt,charStr,charDex)
VALUES (mlkauschwitz,ranger,81,4500,50,50,300,250)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE charClass=ranger,charLevel=81,charLife=4500,charES=50,charInt=50,charStr=300,charDex=250;
```

results in this error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'mlkauschwitz' in 'field list'"
```

Why is it thinking a value is a field?

Using the following PHP:

```
include "db.php";
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$char = array(
    'charClass'=>'ranger',
    'charDex'=>'250',
    'charES'=>'50',
    'charInt'=>'50',
    'charLevel'=>'81',
    'charLife'=>'4500',
    'charName'=>'mlkauschwitz',
    'charStr'=>'300',
);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO chars (charName,charClass,charLevel,charLife,charES,charInt,charStr,charDex) VALUES ('.$char["charName"].','.$char["charClass"].','.$char["charLevel"].','.$char["charLife"].','.$char["charES"].','.$char["charInt"].','.$char["charStr"].','.$char["charDex"].') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE charClass='.$char["charClass"].',charLevel='.$char["charLevel"].',charLife='.$char["charLife"].',charES='.$char["charES"].',charInt='.$char["charInt"].',charStr='.$char["charStr"].',charDex='.$char["charDex"].';';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($stmt) {
    try {
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
}
```

charName field is unique/primary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values in the resultant SQL need to be quoted.
Using pdo, you should do something like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO chars (charName,charClass,charLevel,charLife,charES,charInt,charStr,charDex) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE charClass='.$char["charClass"].',charLevel='.$char["charLevel"].',charLife='.$char["charLife"].',charES='.$char["charES"].',charInt='.$char["charInt"].',charStr='.$char["charStr"].',charDex='.$char["charDex"].';';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($stmt) {
    try {
        $stmt->execute(array($char["charName"],$char["charClass"],$char["charLevel"],$char["charLife"],$char["charES"],$char["charInt"],$char["charStr"],$char["charDex"]));
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
}
```

Not sure of the exact syntax, but you can look it up in the manual. This ensures that PDO quotes all the values correctly, and avoids mysql injection issues.

Answer (score 0):

if mlkauschwitz is not column but value, you have quote it

see mysqli_escape_string()

Comment: Note, this won't _add_ quotes to the strings. Also, it's not necessary with PDO, as PDO takes care of quoting and escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to `INSERT INTO chars (charName,charClass,charLevel,charLife,charES,charInt,charStr,charDex)
VALUES ('mlkauschwitz','ranger','81','4500','50','50','300','250')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE charClass='ranger',charLevel='81',charLife='4500',charES='50',charInt='50',charStr='300',charDex='250';`